# Why should you dispatch an action to update the state and not update the store directly in react/redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

Explain briefly about... Why should you dispatch an action to update the state and not update the store directly in react/redux?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Redux is a dataflow pattern that is event (=action)-based. Only actions lead to store changes. Also, those have to happen without changing the old state, but by creating a new one.

This is a base assumption and un-bendable rule, because that is the purpose of Redux - moving applciation logic out of your UI layer.

All tooling depends on that assumption - e.g. react-redux will only check for new state after a dispatch and it will do so by comparing current and last state value.

If you want to directly modify it, you simply have gone for the wrong library.
There are libraries that allow for such things, like mobx or valtio, but it will not work with Redux.